# How to change thickness

Tags: modeling, modifiers

So I am following a tutorial about character modeling (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DAAwy_l4jw4). The basis consists of simple vertex and edges combined with the skin modifier and subdivision. When fingers come into play, my take on this looks like this...[image: character]

When it should look rather like this...[image: thin fingers]

So is there a way to make the fingers thinner? I couldn´t find anything like that in the modifiers.

Comment: The vertex radius should do that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this.

A. Select a vertex in edit mode. Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>A</kbd> and drag with mouse left/right to scale your vertex and skin.

[image]

B. Open the *Properties Panel* ( <kbd>N</kbd> key) and edit *Vertex Data > Radius X* or *Radius Y*, this way you can do some exact changes in either x and y axis easily.

[image]

Comment: Yes that´s it. Thanks!